# Not able to set Properties setProperty

Tags: java, properties

I've came across very weird scenario. Not sure, its logical or not, but please bother.

I've two elements, one is ***jar file*** and second is ***ETL tool*** which is completely a *advanced Java based ETL tool.*

I've imported my `jar` in one ETL's job. What's happening in jar is that when I'm loading too many parameters from JSON so that I could use them in my ETL code. Those parameters are being set using Properties method `setProperty` and I am able to access all in ETL code using `getProperty`.

But there is one class in jar, looks like below :

```
public class SetRecordCount {

    static String count;

    public void execute(Properties context) {
      context.setProperty("Count",context.getProperty("RecordCount")); // not accessible
      count = context.getProperty("RecordCount"); // Here accessible
    }
}
```

I am not able to access `context.getProperty("Count")` in ETL, and it returns null. But why its coming null, because I am able to set all parameters coming in JSON in this way only (`context.setProperty`) and able to access them in ETL. (Note: I am using same Properties instance (context) to load parameters)

But If I set that count value to class's member, them I am able to get that in my ETL code using `SetRecordCount.count`

**Isn't it strange ..?**

**Can anyone please share what am doing wrong to access value using** `context.setProperty("Count",context.getProperty("RecordCount"))`?

Comment: What's stopping you from swapping the two statements and rewriting the second to `context.setProperty("Count",count);` Does that work?

Comment: @JimGarrison, Aha, that's nice..I'll try sure...!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
// First, retrieve count and then set that in context.
count = context.getProperty("RecordCount");
context.setProperty("Count", count);
```